# Cant get job description using Jenkins slack notifcation plugin with pipeline script

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins, pipeline, slack

I am using the slack notification plugin with Jenkins and I already set the notification settings in Jenkinsfile. I want to preview the job description on the Slack channel, and I am setting it on Jenkinsfile like this: Info: `${currentBuild.description}` but I am getting on the slack channel Info: NUll although I already putting a description on the job.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you are not setting the description properly. Log the description before the slack call and check whether you are getting the description correctly. Something like the one below works for me.

```
currentBuild.description = "This is a Description"

pipeline {
    agent any
    stages {
        stage('Test') {
            steps {
                echo "${currentBuild.description}"
                summary = "The Job ${currentBuild.description} worked"
                slackSend(channel: channel, color: colorCode, message: summary)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: sry for my later to reply, i will try and back to u, tnx for ur helping !